# Setting up a SaaS

Tags: database-design, cakephp, saas

I am thinking of deploying a CakePHP app as a Software as a Service (SaaS), to simply offer different instances of the app through one central system.

Off the top of my head, this would all run off one code base with a global account and user models (habtm) and each account that would sign up would create a entire new database (with all the app-specific tables) and with some clever bootstrapping/rewrites in place to set the app up at `https://myurl.com/account1/controller/action`, `https://myurl.com/account2/controller/action` and so on. One issue that arises from this is that database migrations will have to handled very carefully (ie 1 alteration will have to happen on each clients database!).

**Is this feasible with CakePHP?** If not what should I use? Project is still in its infancy so I'm open to ideas. One of the things that seems a bleak area is getting CakePHP to access the user/accounts table from a different database (and a different connection?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you are looking to have many databases instead of just one?  Doing it the way you mentioned is a nightmare to manage and maintain.

You should be able to do everything in one database.

This also makes migrations and updates much simpler and also removes your issue about access to user accounts b/c they are all in one table.

Yes, CakePHP will handle what I have mentioned above no problem.